# How to adjust yourself where your colleagues are not understanding to you?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, colleagues, india, politics

I work in a company where electronic circuit parts are manufactured and assembled. I am in the assembly department. We are team of 15 junior and 2 seniors. I have  newly joined and working as junior in the company For each kind of work We need to report the seniors.

But the main problem is that both the seniors are not understanding to few of juniors like me.  They always try to pressure us by pointing out small mistakes in our work. They get angry  quickly if we have a short delay in our work.  seniors always trying to show off. These seniors have some juniors which are always in favor of them and behave like their personal agents. "These juniors" who are our colleagues make complaints about us to seniors without any reason and seniors get angry at us.

I don't want to leave the company as it has good reputation in the market  and work is also of my interest. Salary is also good.

I have recently joined this company after completing my education . I want to be professional.  But I don't understand how to handle this workspace politics where colleagues are not understanding? How to manage both the seniors as well as  "these juniors"?

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it; either endure it or move on. I'd prefer the latter. My father has endured it for like 20 years, it didn't go well for his health.

Comment: Post which country you are in.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am from India

Comment: sagar you said newly joined. Take some time to analyze if you are stupid mistakes. The only thing you can control is your work. Don't try to control others. Learn as much as possible and focus on your work.

Comment: @Learner_101 but sometimes things go out of patience when colleagues do taunting and disturbs you while you are doing your work.

Comment: Well looks like an unprofessional setting. I thing best you can do is ignore them . Once you don't respond, they will try harder to distract you. This means your strategy is working. The other thing you can do is start recording what they are doing and simply report to higher ups. Do the cam recording in front of them. Do not threaten to report. Just report if you at any time feel it must be done. I think you must collect evidence and report.

Comment: Hi @Learner_101, I'm unsure recording is a good idea. Recording all the facts would be almost equal to broke a war with the seniors and their minions. It will be very detrimental to OP. Asia in its entirety, value very much seniority, especially men's one and the obedience that comes out with that seniority. Ask any asians mens who are they scared the most, their dad or their mum... As Alexander said, Sagar's best choice if he wants to stay, is to endure. Once as a senior, he will be able to change things. Not before and any acts contrary will be very similar to self-sabotage.

Comment: Hi @sagar see my comment

Comment: "They always try to pressurize us by drawing small mistakes in our work. They get angry quickly if we do short delay in our work." - I'm not sure what you're saying here: they are pointing out when you make mistakes, and when you're not being as productive as you could be? Are they responsible for quality and productivity of the team? If so, it's their job to point out mistakes and to encourage you to work efficiently. What did you mean by 'malleable' - more forgiving to you, more understanding because you're new? Or accept that you work differently to them? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you!

Comment: @Rup "Not malleable" meaning the seniors don't try to understand that a new person will need some time what to do and how to do your work. Also if you are doing your work honestly,  why should seniors blame you by listening to others ?

Comment: 'Malleable' goes both ways. They need you to adjust, but you need to adjust as well to their way of working.

Comment: To borrow from Inigo Montoya: I do not think "malleable" means what you think it means. What are you actually trying to accomplish? What would a resolved situation look like to you?

Comment: @sagar I changed some of your wording to make it more understandable (e.g. "[malleable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malleable)" does not mean what you think it means). Feel free to [edit] the question if you disagree with any of the changes.

Answer (score 7):

**First as a junior person, it is up to you to adjust to the work place culture not the culture to adjust to you.** A workplace cannot adjust to the desires of every individual who is hired as they all would do things differently from each other.

It is the job of the seniors to point out mistakes and pressure you to perform better. That will happen in virtually every workplace, so get used to it. Do they favor some people, chances are pretty close to 100% that they will. That too is normal and ordinary in any workplace. You need to understand what they want and give it to them in order to be one of the favored people. Clearly you do not.

Until you build up some credibility through good performance and understanding the underlying politics of this workplace, you have virtually no chance of proposing change and getting it implemented. So what you need to concentrate on first is getting that credibility. Then you can work on how things can be improved in the workplace.

Comment: OP has tagged "India" in his question. Problems like what he's mentioning are quite prevalent in the Indian working environment. There are plenty of occasions where the seniors are / management is downright rude and inconsiderate. It isn't like the usual senior person giving skill-related feedback to improve his juniors. They're usually egoistic and unskilled even after several years - just disagreeing with juniors, bossing over them just for the sake of exercising their powers. @sagar Would be great if you can confirm whether this is what you meant.

Comment: Then it is still the workplace culture and you have to adapt to it. I had bosses like that when I was junior too.  As a junior you have no leverage to push for change when the culture accepts that type of behavior. The best you can do is learn to work within the system and then make sure not to treat people that way when you are senior..

Comment: @Mugen that isn't confined to India, most places with a strong hierarchical social structure it leaks into workplaces. You need to understand it and work with it, or side step it.

Comment: @Kilisi Most surprising. And when you say places with a strong hierarchical social structure do you mean different corporations, cities or countries itself?

Comment: Cultures is what I meant, some places have nobles, commoners, and a class below that. It trickles over into the workplace. Some places more so than others, but I have noticed it in a few countries, my own included. Where management often view themselves as superior and act very badly towards underlings and nothing is done about it.

Comment: I think that everyone starts out the way OP describes in one form or another. From experience, you take the beating and simply get better at what you do and people will come to respect that. You earn peoples' favor, whether they're junior, senior, executive, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I belong to a completely different industry, but I can suggest few things.

> I have newly joined and working as junior in the company

As per my experience whenever any new person joins a new company, that person needs to do following,

- Understand company culture
- Understand people around you and their behavior (Why people behave like this?)

> As you said that your senior not understanding you?

Here I suggest that you have to put more effort than other people around you. Also sometimes the company environment is like that and that is their way to suggest you improve your work when you make mistakes. I suggest that when you have some time, go to them and talk to them politely. Ask: "How you improve for the future" and in this way you can break the ice. If you improve and this thing still continues than you may have to think about other job options.

Note: This is completely based on my opinion.